# How to open Custom URL in Jquery Mobile Gmap Plugin

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile, jquery-gmap3

I am trying to create a free app for our city to display public transport route info. Our city have placed all the routes at the below URL.

https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http://www.myciti.org.za/IRT_services.kmz&hl=en&sll=-33.88029,18.50333&sspn=0.231158,0.308647&t=m&z=12

How do I create a Gmap instance to display the content at this URL?

Currently the below code is used to display a map zoomed in on a specific marker:

```
    $('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'center': vars['lat'] + ',' + vars['lon'], 'zoom': 16, 'streetViewControl': false, 'mapTypeControl': false }).bind('init', function() {
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 'foo': 'bar', 'position': vars['lat'] + ',' + vars['lon'] });
    });
```

Thanks for the help!

Regards

Devin

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean information window regarding each cities ?
If so then try Extended Usage (4th option) http://gmap.nurtext.de/examples.html

Comment: Hi Andy. I literally am looking for how to get the below URL onto a mobile gmap. If you go to the link you will see how data has already been captured there via a KMZ file. Thanks for any help with making this happen. - https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http://www.myciti.org.za/IRT_services.kmz&hl=en&sll=-33.88029,18.50333&sspn=0.231158,0.308647&t=m&z=12